# Assigning XML children to variables in a single loop in Python

Tags: python, xml, loops, xpath

I'm still learning XML functions slowly playing with the Pubmed APIs. At the moment I'm using xpath to grab text from the children in an XML and assign them to lists that I am then assigning to a dictionary. [Here](https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&tool=PMA&id=29150897,29149862) is the XML and here is my code:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
import requests
from lxml import etree

article_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&tool=PMA&id=29150897,29149862"
response = requests.get(article_url)
tree = etree.fromstring(response.content)

ids = tree.xpath("//MedlineCitation/PMID[@Version='1']")
journal = [j.text.strip() for j in tree.xpath('//Article//Title')]
year = [y.text.strip() for y in tree.xpath('//PubmedData//History//PubMedPubDate[@PubStatus="medline"]//Year')]
month = [m.text.strip() for m in tree.xpath('//PubmedData//History//PubMedPubDate[@PubStatus="medline"]//Month')]
day = [d.text.strip() for d in tree.xpath('//PubmedData//History//PubMedPubDate[@PubStatus="medline"]//Day')]

result = {_id.text: {"journal": journal, "year": year, "month": month, "day":day} for _id, journal, year, month, day in zip(ids, journal, year, month, day)}
pp(result)
```

So the output is a dictionary:

```
{'29149862': {'day': '19',
              'journal': 'Italian journal of pediatrics',
              'month': '11',
              'year': '2017'},
 '29150897': {'day': '19',
              'journal': 'Respirology (Carlton, Vic.)',
              'month': '11',
              'year': '2017'}}
```

However I am doing that over an XML with 1000 nodes (i.e. each 'journal' and 'year' etc. will have 1000+ items in the list).

I am wondering,

1. if doing the x.text.strip() 4+ times is going to cause unnecessary looping through the XML document and,
2. how I can run a single loop to grab the four things I need and assign them to the lists?

tl;dr: How can I optimize this process? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not beginning every XPath with `//` would be a start. You want specific things that are relative to each other, your over-generous use of `//` everywhere mushes the entire, neatly structured input document into one big mess. Use relative XPaths and ditch the `zip()` approach. Also, `//` triggers a complete subtree search at every point it is used, think about what that means for performance.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, thanks for this. I didn't know how / vs // worked. Doing what you have said has reduced the time for my overall script by about 20x. A great thanks for pointing this out to me.

Comment: Awesome, that's a great improvement! :)

Answer (score 1):

Optimized solution:

```
import requests, pprint
from lxml import etree

article_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&tool=PMA&id=29150897,29149862"
response = requests.get(article_url)
tree = etree.fromstring(response.content)

ids_xpath = '//MedlineCitation/PMID[@Version=1]/text()'
article_xpath = '//Article//Title/text()'
ymd_xpath = '//PubmedData/History/PubMedPubDate[@PubStatus="medline"]/' \
            '*[self::Year or self::Month or self::Day]/text()'
full_xpath = '|'.join((ids_xpath, article_xpath, ymd_xpath))
nodes = tree.xpath(full_xpath)

result = { nodes[i]: dict(zip(('journal', 'year', 'month', 'day'), nodes[1:]))
           for i in range(0, len(nodes), 5)}

pprint.pprint(result)
```

The output:

```
{'29149862': {'day': '19',
              'journal': 'Respirology (Carlton, Vic.)',
              'month': '11',
              'year': '2017'},
 '29150897': {'day': '19',
              'journal': 'Respirology (Carlton, Vic.)',
              'month': '11',
              'year': '2017'}}
```

---

The crucial *xpath* expression will extract and arrange the needed nodes in consecutive manner: `<id> | <journal> | <year> | <month> | <day>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
import requests
from lxml import etree as ET

def extract_items(tree):
    for article in tree.xpath("/PubmedArticleSet/PubmedArticle"):
        item = {}

        citation = article.find('MedlineCitation')
        data = article.find('PubmedData')

        id = citation.findtext('./PMID[@Version = "1"]', default='')
        medline_date = data.find('./History/PubMedPubDate[@PubStatus="medline"]')

        item[id] = {
            'journal': citation.findtext('./Article/Journal/Title', default=''),
            'day': medline_date.findtext('Day', default=''),
            'month': medline_date.findtext('Month', default=''),
            'year': medline_date.findtext('Year', default=''),
        }
        yield item

article_url = "https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml&tool=PMA&id=29150897,29149862"
response = requests.get(article_url)
tree = ET.fromstring(response.content)

for item in extract_items(tree):
    print(item)
```

Note how everything uses relative XPaths (starting with `./`) and the slow "descendant" shorthand `//` is not even necessary at all. I avoid querying the same path twice, and if I want to go to a direct child of an element, I simply use the child's name instead of a new path.

Result:

```
{'29150897': {'journal': 'Respirology (Carlton, Vic.)', 'day': '19', 'month': '11', 'year': '2017'}}
{'29149862': {'journal': 'Italian journal of pediatrics', 'day': '19', 'month': '11', 'year': '2017'}}
```

I am not a big fan of structuring data like this. I would recommend:

```
{
    {'id': '29150897', 'journal': 'Respirology (Carlton, Vic.)', 'day': '19', 'month': '11', 'year': '2017'},
    {'id': '29149862', 'journal': 'Italian journal of pediatrics', 'day': '19', 'month': '11', 'year': '2017'}
]
```

as this will turn out to be much easier to work with.